# Spelling Suggestions with django-haystack and Solr

Tags: django, spell-checking, django-haystack

I'm getting "None" for spelling suggestions.

First, I have this set in my settings.py file:

```
HAYSTACK_INCLUDE_SPELLING = True
```

I have rebuilt the index:

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
```

and updated it for good measure

```
python manage.py update_index
```

The search works correctly.  When I search for "Charger", it returns the results that match.  So in my views.py, I then tried:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
def testpage(request):

    test_results = SearchQuerySet().auto_query('Chargr')
    spelling_suggestion = test_results.spelling_suggestion()

    return render_to_response('testpage.html', {
        'test': test_results,   
        'spelling_suggestion': spelling_suggestion
    })
```

However, my template:

```
<html>
    <body>

        {{ test }}<p>
        {{ spelling_suggestion }}

    </body>
</html>
```

Still returns nothing:

```
[]

None
```

Obviously, I expected nothing for {{ test }}, but shouldn't I get something for {{ spelling_suggestion }}?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did finally figure this out (with some help from the Haystack message group)

There is some detail [here](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/installing_search_engines.html#spelling-suggestions%5d) on configuration changes that must be made.  In addition, I had to add lines to haystack's views.py file (under def extra_context):

```
spelling = self.results.spelling_suggestion(self.query)
return {'suggestion': spelling, . . .
```

Then I added {{ suggest }} to my output template